# How can I count times a pattern of variables occurs?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to count the number of times a pattern of values occurs for variables in R:

My dataset is similar to this:

```
   a b c d   n
1  0 1 0 0 236
2  0 1 0 1  40
3  0 1 1 0  11
4  0 1 1 1   6
5  0 0 0 0 352
10 0 0 0 1  38
```

I created this data through using this code to count the number of times each pattern occurs in the dataframe:

```
df %>% 
  count(a,b,c,d)
```

I'm trying to count for example how many times the variable A has the value of 1 at the same time as other variables,

for example:
d is answered with a value of 1 for once instance in other columns for a total of: 1 instances ( which gives an sum from the n column of 38)
d is answered with a value of 1 for two instances in other columns for a total of: 2 instances ( which gives an sum from the n column of 51)
d is answered with a value of 1 for three instances in other columns for a total of: 1 instances ( which gives an sum from the n column of 6)

Is there a way in R to calculate this for each of the variables a-d, perhaps with ddply?

the code for the dataframe is:

```
df <- structure(list(a = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("-98", 
"0", "1"), class = "factor"), b = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), c = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    d = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("-98", 
    "0", "1"), class = "factor"), n = c(236L, 40L, 11L, 6L, 352L, 
    38L)), row.names = 5:10, class = "data.frame")
```

My expected output looks like this:

```
  1     2  3 
A 0     0  0 
B 236   51 6
C 0     11 6
D 38    51 6
```

Comment: Could you include your expected output

Comment: I have read what you wrote about 10 times and still can't understand what you want to count!

Comment: @Onyambu i've added my desired output

Comment: @MarekFiołka I'm trying to count the number of times the value of 1 occurs in each column, first by itself and then alongside other counts. I have added my desired output. I hope that helps!

Comment: I understand now! With one small caveat: the expected result for `C` should be `C 0 11 6` and not as you wrote `C 11 0 6`.
We'll do something about it.

Comment: How comes D is given the value of `38 51 6`? should it not be `38 40 6`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)%>%
  mutate(rowSums(across(a:d)) * across(a:d)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-n) %>%
  filter(value > 0)%>%
  xtabs(n~., .)

   value
name   1   2   3
   b 236  51   6
   c   0  11   6
   d  38  40   6
```

Comment: A great solution. Especially it is `rowSums (across (a: d)) * across (a: d)`! I wouldn't have thought of anything simple myself.